# Cannot build cordova windows platform (error APPX1609)

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, winjs, windows-10-mobile

Since updating to `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (KB3165756)` today I cannot build my cordova windows application anymore by:

```
cordova build windows -- --appx=8.1-phone
```

Because of the following error:

> Package.appxmanifest(2,2): error APPX1609: The package contains a Debug framework reference 'Name=Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, MinVersion=1.0.9651.0'. Ensure all framework references in the package are valid frameworks hosted by the Store.

My working environment:

- Visual Studio 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Cordova 6.3.1
- Cordova-Windows 4.4.2

Comment: Are you referencing other project in your solution? And does the project build well using VS?

Comment: My Solution has `Windows Phone 8.1`, `Windows 8.1` and `Universal Windows` as valid project targets and addtionally it has included another `*.csproj` from the `cordova-plugin-vibration`. So the answer to 1. question would probably - Yes. I am building with `cordova` and `gulp`. I am using `VS2015` only for device deployment...

Comment: It seems this problem occures when you change the target. For example from windows 8.1 to windows 10.0. However after removing and adding the platform again FIXED the issue. thanks for @Beat for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-adding the `windows` platform actually helped me:

```
cordova platform remove windows
cordova platform add windows
```